# How to set offset on last element in dynamic scrollable Path in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit, infinite-scroll

i'm trying to construct a view with continuous path as graph in scrollView.

I'm receiving data from BLE device and transform them into a vector based on timestamps. While vector is growing in time in width i'm tying to follow it in scrollView. I tired implementation with ScrollViewReader but with no luck, becouse if i understood well i should have id of element i want to scroll to. It's not possible as i know becouse whole signal is one path drawing at once.

I tried to set offset of uiScrollView based on last element width but i can't get scrollView growing as Path with chart is...

I used implementation of uiScrollView wraper: https://gist.github.com/jfuellert/67e91df63394d7c9b713419ed8e2beb7

and in it i'm drawing a path based on values and constant value as xStep

struct LineChart: Shape {

```
let geoProxy: GeometryProxy
@Binding var lead: ECGLead
@Binding var timestamps: [Int]
var n: vDSP_Length{
    return vDSP_Length(lead.channelVector.count)
}


let stride = vDSP_Stride(1)
var xPosition: Binding<CGFloat>
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    
    Path { path in
        
        let xStep = 0.00015 * geoProxy.size.width
        var currentX: CGFloat = xStep
        let signal = transformIntoSignal(lead: lead , timestamps: timestamps)
        
        
        path.move(to: .zero)
        //if signal.count
        signal.forEach{ signalValue in
            //let yStep = CGFloat($0) * geoProxy.frame(in: .local).height
            //print("X: \(currentX) Y: \($0)")
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: currentX, y: CGFloat(signalValue)))
            currentX += xStep
            print("Last x: \(currentX)")
            
            //print("Checking xStep = \(currentX)")
        }
    }
}
func transformIntoSignal(lead: ECGLead, timestamps: [Int]) -> [Float] {
    var outputSignal = [Float](repeating: 0,
                               count: Int(n))
    
    let time = timestamps.map{Float($0)}
    
    
    vDSP_vgenp(lead.channelVector, stride,
               time, stride,
               &outputSignal, stride,
               vDSP_Length(lead.channelVector.count),
               vDSP_Length(timestamps.count))
    
    return outputSignal
    
}
```

}

With that path i'm trying to give it's maxWidth = .inifity to be able to grow in scrollView

```
       ZStack(){
            
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 170, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 60, idealHeight: 90, maxHeight: 90, alignment: .center)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
                .overlay(
                    ScrollableView($lineOffset, animationDuration: TimeInterval(1), content: {
                            //HStack{
                        LineChart(vector: animatableVector, geoProxy: geoProxy,lead: $ecgLead,timestamps: $timeStamps, xPosition: $lastPointX)
                                    .stroke(appGreen, lineWidth: 1)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 170, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 35, idealHeight: 40, maxHeight: 50,alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center))
                        
                        })//.frame(minWidth: 120, idealWidth: 170, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 35, idealHeight: 50, maxHeight: 60,alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center))

                )
```

With uiScrollView wrapper i tried to programmatically scroll to content offset but each time i saw jumping view around some middle value and end continuously.

Here is update method from UIkit wraper mentioned above:

```
 func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) {
    
    viewController.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator   = self.showsScrollIndicator
    viewController.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = self.showsScrollIndicator
    viewController.updateContent(self.content)
    viewController.scrollView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    let lastPoint = viewController.scrollView.contentSize.width
    let lastPointOffset = viewController.scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let tmp = viewController.scrollView.visibleSize.width
    let contentWidth = viewController.scrollView.bounds.width
    print("Check last point: \(lastPoint)")
    print("Check last point offset: \(lastPointOffset)")
    print("Check tmp: \(contentWidth)")
    viewController.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: lastPoint, y: 0), animated: true)
    viewController.scrollView.bounds.width
    
    let duration: TimeInterval                = self.duration(viewController)
    let newValue: CGPoint                     = self.offset.wrappedValue
    viewController.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = !self.disableScroll
    
    if self.stopScrolling.wrappedValue {
        viewController.scrollView.setContentOffset(viewController.scrollView.contentOffset, animated:true)
        return
    }
    
    guard duration != .zero else {
        viewController.scrollView.contentOffset = newValue
        return
    }
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {
        viewController.scrollView.contentOffset = newValue
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

My question is how to make scroll always focused on last element of growing array of this signal in scrollView. Is it not working becouse somewhere is width not growing correctly? Or i misunderstood somewhere? For now i don't have an idea where to continue

Thank you in advance for answering my question. Any help will by really appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Since you're working in UIKit, it would be good to delete the swiftUI tags.  That's a separate way of working with the UI.

Comment: Thank you for response, did it :) Hope it helps :)